# How to add new Column with 'ddl-auto=update' and 'nullable=false'

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

If I add a column like this to an existing entity, hibernate fails to add the column, since there are existing rows without a value:

```
@Column(name = "width", nullable = false)
private int width;
```

Fails with this error:

```
2015-11-14 20:33:41.163 ERROR 9068 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table texture add column width int4 not null
2015-11-14 20:33:41.163 ERROR 9068 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : FEHLER: Spalte „width“ enthält NULL-Werte
```

I do not want a default value in my database column definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be altering a table with existing data, so it is not possible to add a column to existing rows if the column is not nullable, and no default value is specified.

So I think you need to allow nullable or specify a default value, you have no other option ...

Comment: So I probably do the nut null check in the app with @NotNull and migrate the DB in a late version.

Comment: Is there is way to create column with not nullable value or no default value?